# changing font colour when using Replace

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code in a vb.net application.

I open a word document and replace the text using this code:

```
oDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="Invoice", ReplaceWith:="Invoice - Paid: " + paid_date, Replace:=word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
```

how can i change the font colour of the text?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: thanks - not really much help answering the question though. thats not exactly the end of the world